# phase and k space in matlab for dicom image

Tags: image, matlab, transformation

Assume you have `DI-COM MR image` using "mat-lab".

**Question:**

1. How do you transfer `Di-com(MR image)` to `k-space`?
2. how do you transfer `Di-com image`  into `phase-space`?

Answer (score 1):

The k space representation of the dicom image is the FFT of the image data. Use `dicomread` to get the data, then use `fft` for Fourier transform.

I believe the phase information is extracted from the angle of the FFT (which has real and imaginary components as you know).